# QGIS geotrace languages from a given image of a map

Tags: qgis, georeferencing, vectorization

I have a linguistic map of the Caucasus and I need to geotrace the languages that are on the map, preferably in QGIS.

Is there any way in which I can do it easily?

Here is the map:

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by geotrace?

Comment: See https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/428811/88814

Answer (score 3):

Save your map as something like png or jpeg that you can later bring into QGIS. Use the **georeferencer plugin** tool to georeference the map in QGIS. It helps to start with a background map of the area you are interested in QGIS, Open Street Map for example. There is a tutorial by Steven Bernard that does a great job of explaining the process [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B8Y4BjeHhlE).

After importing the image and geo-referencing, you can digitize(trace) the boundaries of the language regions and create polygons.