# Creating polygons from rasters using color values via a color sampler in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, georeferencing, select

This seems like a question that should have been asked, but the trick with all this is in knowing how to ask the question. I would like to use the background satellite imagery from GE or Bing or whatever source and I want to use a color picker (eyedropper) to select a color value and also "add" to the color range using the Shift key as you do in Photoshop to build a range of selected colors. I want that range to be selected with a boundary/perimeter defining the selected color ranges and then convert/save/export to KML/KMZ or .SHP or whatever vector format QGIS may offer beyond that. I'm doing this for complex detailed vegetation cover mapping.  It would be nice to be able to use a bounding box via a rectangle or ellipse or whatever shape and have that as the extent to which a "magic wand" would grab all the values selected as well.  Again, it seems like this has to have been addressed.

I can get a cut out version of the polygons using the tools in Photoshop, but getting that jpeg to work geospatially is likely a nonstarter even after putting it in Illustrator and exporting a DXF. There is still the sizing and geo-referencing.  I used the Freehand Georeference tool but that doesn't allow the exportation of the jpeg to vector. Unless that is done through a  separate set of tools.

Comment: This thread may give some clue: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/417429/extracting-pixels-from-a-raster-based-on-a-given-tolerance-value-as-in-photoshop